# Utilizing a newer standalone glibc

Tags: compiling, gcc, version, glibc

We're running RHEL6, which only officially supports glibc 2.12.  A user is requesting that we install a newer version.

I grabbed 2.18 from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/ and had no trouble running configure/make.

However when I attempt a small program to test it, I don't get the desired result:

**test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include </scratch/new-glibc-testing/include/gnu/libc-version.h>
int main (void) { puts (gnu_get_libc_version ()); return 0; }
```

I then compile and run with:

```
gcc test.c
./a.out
```

And the output I get is:

```
2.12
```

when I was hoping to get:

```
2.18
```

I also tried:

```
gcc -I/scratch/new-glibc-testing/include test.c
```

and changed the define line to:

```
#include <gnu/libc-version.h>
```

which compiles, but gives the same result (2.12).

I tried also using -nostdlib, ex:

```
gcc -nostdlib -I/scratch/new-glibc-testing test.c
```

This, however, throws errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000400144
/tmp/cc6x03Do.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `gnu_get_libc_version'
test.c:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `puts'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`gcc --version` results in:
**gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)**

Comment: I'd suggest you install a VM for the user if he/she wants a newer glibc. It's a crucial part of any Linux OS and you risk hosing your whole system.

Comment: `chroot` or lx container will do, no need for a full vm in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the link path as well (-L -l) flags - only specifying the includes is not enough (in fact, you're risking application crashes when using headers from one version and libraries from a different one). You may also need -rpath and -rpath-link options passed to the linker, depending on your setup.

As mentioned in comments, it is rather difficult and dangerous to maintain multiple versions of the glibc in the same machine image. A safer approach is to setup a "slim" container (such as `chroot` jail or using lx) and to install a different system image into it with libraries updated as required.